# Npm http-server não executado depois de ser instalado

Tags: node.js, npm

Boa tarde, sobre npm (node package manager) instalando o http-server, alguém teria idéia porque o http-server não está sendo reconhecido?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Editando --->

com o live-server mesma coisa... alguma detalhe de configuração do path...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você deu o comando `npm i -g http-server`?

Comment: sim... fiz a instalação global... estava funcionando até quarta-feira... fui abrir agora e simplesmente não funcionou!!! tentei reinstalar, reiniciar a máquina... mesmo assim, sem resultado... tô partindo pra tentar o(https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server)....

Comment: estou pensando em reinstalar o nodejs... será necessário?

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido o problema estava na configuração do caminho pro npm que contém como dependência o http-server, nesse caso (c:\users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm) ...

[image: caminho da variável global]

[image: prompt cmd]